# What is the error in calculated volume of cylinder, given the measurements of length and radius?

Tags: geometry, volume, error-propagation

Measured   length of the rod is $15 \pm 0.4$ cm and the radius of the rod is $6.1 \pm 0.2$ cm. What is the error in calculated volume? (two decimal places)

What i've tried is

$$V=\pi   r^2  l$$
$$V=1753.48 \text{ cm}^3$$

$$DV/ 1753.48= 2(0.2/6.1) + (0.4)/15$$
$$DV = 161.74 \text{ cm}^3$$

But I got it wrong.

Answer (score 2):

$V(r,l)=\pi r^2l$, so $$\begin{align}
V(r+\Delta r,l+\Delta l)&\approx V(r,l)+\frac{\partial V}{\partial r}\Delta r+\frac{\partial V}{\partial l}\Delta l\\
&\approx V(r,l)+2\pi r l\Delta r+\pi r^2\Delta l
\end{align}$$

So error in $V$ is $2\pi r l\Delta r+\pi r^2\Delta l$.

---

Note this does not factor in statistics/probability. If the given information is meant to convey that $l$ has a Normal distribution centered at $15$ with $\sigma=0.4$, and that $r$ has a Normal distribution centered at $6.1$ with $\sigma=0.2$, then $\Delta V$ should be computed as $$\sqrt{\left(2\pi r l\Delta r\right)^2+\left(\pi r^2\Delta l\right)^2}$$